# How to get a toggle button from saved preferences and save states twice?

Tags: java, android, save, toggle

I'm having trouble trying to get my sound to play, the code the play the second boolean value, and im wondering if the save is having trouble or something.. I have a variable set as a private static int that can be changed between 1 and 2. After then I have a SharedPreferences editor changing the values, then third I have a clickable button that reads the shared preference for two seperate occasions. It doesn't work at all And I am wondering if an static int can be used to change seperate SharedPreferences occasions. heres my code

button

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        switch(ButtonConfig) {
            case '1':
                if(ButtonConfig == 1){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(MY_BUTTON_PREF, isChecked);
                editor.apply();}
                break;

            case '2':
                if(ButtonConfig == 2){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(AAA, isChecked);
                editor.apply();}
                break;


        }  }
});
```

play button

```
Playx2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean flag = preferences.getBoolean(MY_BUTTON_PREF, false);
        toggleButton.setChecked(flag);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        boolean flag1 = preferences.getBoolean(AAA, false);
        toggleButton.setChecked(flag1);
```

declarations

```
Button Play;
private static int ButtonConfig;
public static int Options;
private static final String MY_SHARED_PREFERENCES = "SharedPreferences";
private static final String MY_BUTTON_PREF = "button1";
private static final String MY_SHARED_PREFERENCES2 = "SharedPreferences2";
private static final String AAA = "button500";
```

and outside I have my onClick methods

```
public void D1(View view) {
boolean checked = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
if (checked) {
    switch (toggleButton) {

        case '1':
            if (ButtonConfig == 1) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("button1", true);
                editor.apply();
                soundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
            break;

        case '2':
            if (ButtonConfig == 2) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("button500", true);
                editor.apply();
                soundPool.play(sound2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
            break;
    }
} else {
    switch(ButtonConfig){

        case '1'  :

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("button1", false);
    editor.apply();
    break;

        case '2'   :

            editor = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences2", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("button500", false);
            editor.apply();
            break;

}
}}

public void S49(View view) {
boolean checked = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
if (checked) {

    ButtonConfig = 1;
}else{
}}

public void S50(View view) {
boolean checked = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
if (checked) {

    ButtonConfig = 2;
}else{
} }
```

The two buttons have an int value that they return for the cases, but everytime I try to load the two seperate button values, it loads the first one as checked and second as unchecked. The sound also doesn't play in the case statement, but if I take them outside they place just fine. Can anyone help? I would really appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it turns out I need to retrieve both boolean values and cannot use int for retrieval of values.